# ERROR: undefined method `python' for #<Chef::Node::Attribute:0x00000003f78ef8>

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, cookbook

I am newbie to chef.
I try install python by chef into Amazon EC2.
I made a node in chef-repo/nodes folder something as mynode.com.json
I have a run_list in mynode.com.json:

```
"run_list": [
    "recipe[python]"
  ],
```

Then I call:

```
"knife solo cook mynode.com"
```

I got this error:

```
/home/ec2-user/chef-solo/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/python/attributes/default.rb:

 16:  # WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 17:  # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 18:  # limitations under the License.
 19:  #
 20:  
 21:  default['python']['install_method'] = 'package'
 22:  
 23>> if python['install_method'] == 'package'
 24:    case platform
 25:    when "smartos"
 26:      default['python']['prefix_dir']         = '/opt/local'
 27:    else
 28:      default['python']['prefix_dir']         = '/usr'
 29:    end
 30:  else
 31:    default['python']['prefix_dir']         = '/usr/local'
 32:  end

System Info:
------------
chef_version=13.1.31
platform=amazon
platform_version=2017.03
ruby=ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
program_name=chef-solo worker: ppid=12199;start=09:16:41;
executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-solo


Running handlers:
[2017-06-11T09:16:42+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2017-06-11T09:16:42+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2017-06-11T09:16:42+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2017-06-11T09:16:42+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 01 seconds
[2017-06-11T09:16:42+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /home/ec2-user/chef-solo/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2017-06-11T09:16:42+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /home/ec2-user/chef-solo/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2017-06-11T09:16:42+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2017-06-11T09:16:42+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2017-06-11T09:16:42+00:00] ERROR: undefined method `python' for #<Chef::Node::Attribute:0x00000003f78ef8>
[2017-06-11T09:16:42+00:00] ERROR: undefined method `python' for #<Chef::Node::Attribute:0x00000003f78ef8>
```

Is there anyone can help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That cookbook (`python`) is deprecated and does not work with Chef 13. Use `poise-python` instead.